# Javascript - Get an object's name from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, material-ui

This may be a really daft question or an impossible question..

I have a table which uses two arrays of objects like so:

```
const columnData = [
  { id: 'name', label: 'Name' },
  { id: 'value', label: 'Value' }
];

const rowData = [
  { name: 'Name 01', value: 100 },
  { name: 'Name 02', value: 150 },
  { name: 'Name 03', value: 200 },
];
```

I am writing this as a separate `react` component so I can reuse it and just change the two sets of data passed in as props. This is all fine and working, however I am struggling to figure out how to `map` the rows and columns to be dynamic.

i.e.:

```
...
{this.props.rowData.map(row => {
  return (
    <tr>
    {this.props.columnData.map(column => {
      return (
        <td>{row.(THE_COLUMN_ID_TO_GET_THE_VALUE)}</td>
      );
    }
    </tr>
  );
}
...
```

I hope I make some sense here as it's a bit vague.. I basically want to get the value from `rowData` using the column `id` name. EG: `<td>{row.name}</td><td>{row.value}</td>` without hardcoding the item.

Comment: Use the bracket notation like `<td>{row[column.id]}</td>`.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! I knew it would be something simple. If you want to throw this in as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [] syntax on objects to obtain values based on computed properties.

```
{this.props.rowData.map(row => {
 return (
   <tr>
     {this.props.columnData.map(column => {
       return (
        <td>{row[column.id]}</td>
       );
     }
   </tr>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to get the property of the row that matches the column id? You can access a property with dynamic name using square brackets like `row[column.id]`

```
{this.props.rowData.map(row => {
  return (
    <tr>
    {this.props.columnData.map(column => {
      return (
        <td>{row[column.id]}</td>
      );
    }
    </tr>
  );
}
```